# Scroll snap on element's grandchildren - CSS & React Router pattern

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, react-router

My webpage uses React Router to render out components. For eg.: I have a '/' route where it renders out the nav bar and the footer.

**Now I would like to implement a landing page where as the user scrolls it snaps to certain divs (features of the product). 
The problem is that css' scroll-snap parameter only works in Parent-Child relationship, not on parent-grandchildren or further down the hierarchy.**

Is there any work around? I have looked into the scroll snap npm module, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
<Provider id='parent'> */ scrolling div -> top level hiearchy the top level of react router */
   <Route id='child> /* this would be a route */
       <div id='wrapper'> /* top level component in route */
           <p> Some text </p> /*content to snap to*/
           <p> Some text </p> /*content to snap to*/
       </div>
   </Route>
</Provider>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would like to do this too.